# jQuery ui dialog overlay and ajax injected html

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, dialog, overlay

I have a problem with a site (unfortunately I can't provide a link because it's on a staging environment).

I have a jqueryui dialog that opens when page loads, if you scroll down the overlay covers all of it.
Then some part of the page is updated by ajax calls and the height of the page increase and that's the issue, the overlay don't covers all the page any more and the bottom content is accessible.

I can see that the overlay adapts to certain changes, like resize of the page.. is there a way to update it when scrolling down for example? that *could* solve my issue

I'm sorry I can't provide a link that shows the issue..

Regards,
Gianpiero

Comment: Maybe you can create a simple jsfiddle, adding the important stuff only, reproducing the problem? Then it's easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar situation I found a successful workaround by triggering a window resize event after each asynchronous DOM change:

```
$(window).resize();
```

Comment: Hi Marty, thank you for your answer!
Actually that's what I did and it worked pretty well.. until we don't have too many ajax calls in the page :)